# How to redirect route outside of a ASP.NET MVC3 controller in custom attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I want to know how to redirect to a particular route from outside the controller. I have a custom attribute that I need to redirect the route in.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // Want to redirect to route here.

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should work

```
public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Want to redirect to route here.
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("routename", routeValues)

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```